# need to know what url to use here. CalDav URl. Can someone help me?

Tags: python

I need to know what url to use here. I tried Google Calendar but it didn't work. Can someone help me?

```
import caldav

client = caldav.DAVClient(url="??????", username=""password="")
principal = client.principal()
for calendar in principal.calendars():
    for event in calendar.events():
        ical_text = event.data
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? What is the expected output? Why do you need Google Calendar or CalDav? Also, please fix the indentation.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide Also, you will want to be VERY careful putting username and password for your GMail account in plaintext in a script.